# How to remove some values from a 4-dimensional matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, multidimensional-array

I'm working with a 4-dimensional matrix (Year, Simulation, Flow, Time instant: 10x5x20x10) in R. I need to remove some values from the matrix. For example, for year 1 I need to remove simulations number 1 and 2; for year 2 I need to remove simulation number 5.

Can anyone suggest me how I can make such changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Arrays* (which is how R documentation usually refers to higher-dimensional 'matrices') can be indexed with negative values in the same way as matrices or vectors: a negative value removes the corresponding row/column/slice. So if you wanted to remove year 1 completely (for example), you could use `a[-1,,,]`; to remove simulation 5 completely, `a[,-5,,]`.

However, arrays can't be "ragged", there has to be *something* in every row/column/slice combination. You could replace the values you want to remove with `NA`s (and then make sure to account for the `NA`s appropriately when computing, e.g. using `na.rm = TRUE` in `sum()`/`min()`/`max()`/`median()`/etc.): `a[1,1:2,,] <- NA` or `a[2,5,,] <- NA` in your examples.

If you knew that all values of Flow and Time would always be present, you could store your data as a list of lists of matrices: e.g.

```r
results <- list(Year1 = list(Simulation1 = matrix(...),
                             Simulation2 = matrix(...),
                             ...),
                Year2 = list(Simulation1 = matrix(...),
                             Simulation2 = matrix(...),
                             ...))
```

Then you could easily remove years or simulations within years (by setting them to `NULL`, but it would make indexing a little bit harder (e.g. "retrieve Simulation1 values for all years" would require an `lapply` or a loop across years).

Comment: Correct. I've suggested an alternative data structure.

Comment: Clear! Thank you very much for your help! As a workaround I thought of creating three new matrices :
df1 <- a[1,-c(1:2),,]
df2 <- a[2,-5,,]
df3 <- a[3:7,,,]
   How can i combine them in order to have a unique (4-dimensional) array?

Comment: I don't think you can do that. Arrays *can't be ragged*